# CS 50- Pset 1 Mario Program

Tags: c, loops, debugging, cs50

the problem set asks us to create a half pyramid using hashes. Here is a link to an image of how it should look-

[image]

I get the idea and have written the program until printing the spaces (which I have replaced by "_" just so that I can test the first half of it.

However, when I try to run my program, it doesn't go beyond the do-while loop. In other words, it keeps asking me for the height of the pyramid and does not seem to run the for loop at all. I've tried multiple approaches but this problem seems to persist.

Any help would be appreciated!

Below is my code-

```
# include <cs50.h> 
# include <stdio.h>

int main(void)

{
    int height; 

    do 
    {
        printf("Enter the height of the pyramid: ");
        height = GetInt(); 
    }
    while (height > 0 || height < 24); 

    for (int rows = 1; rows <= height, rows++) 
    {
        for (int spaces = height - rows; spaces > 0; spaces--)
        { 
            printf("_");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Running this program yields the following output-

```
Enter the height of the pyramid: 11
Enter the height of the pyramid: 1231
Enter the height of the pyramid: aawfaf
Retry: 12
Enter the height of the pyramid:
```

Comment: `while (height > 0 || height < 24); ` is cause the problem. Always true.

Comment: Where did that prompt `Retry` come from?

Comment: In case you were curious how to do this with a single-for-loop and cheat per line output with justified, precision-modified string printing, [see it live](http://ideone.com/ojoTkP).

Comment: It's part of the `cs50.h` library @TomFenech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your do/while loop condition is incorrect - change:

```
do {
    ...
} while (height > 0 || height < 24);
```

to either:

```
do {
    ...
} while (height <= 0 || height >= 24);
```

or:

```
do {
    ...
} while (!(height > 0 && height < 24));
```

(whichever you consider to be more readable/intuitive).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I just had a quick question about the logic behind your suggested edit. If we want the height to be between 1 and 23 (inclusive), why should the while condition tell height to be less than or equal to 0 and greater than or equal to 24?

Comment: @boametaphysica: we're testing to see if the height is *invalid*, so if it's <= 0 *or* >= 24, then it's invalid, otherwise it must be in the range 1..23, which is valid. You can express this in other ways, if it makes it more intuitive, e.g. `while (height <= 0 || height >= 24)` is equivalent to `while (height < 1 || height > 23)`.

Comment: Okay, I understand it now. I want the loop to break instead of letting it go on and on as the do-while loop and that is why I need a condition that will cause it to break. Thank you very much once again!

Answer (score -2):

is this more simple

```
         for(int i=0;i<8;i++) {

             for(int j=0;j < (8-i); j++) 
             {

                 System.out.print(" ");
             }
            for(int k=0;k<=(i+1);k++)
            {

                System.out.print("#");
            }
            System.out.println();  
        }
```